# What is the network address for a folder shared on a Mac computer?

Tags: macos, network-shares, file-sharing

I'm trying to get a scanner to be able to scan to a Mac.  The person wants to be able to choose their computer from the scanner and scan to a folder on their MacBook.  For the Windows computers I set up, I just created a shared folder, then input in the scanner's web interface to scan to `\\PCNAME\SHARED FOLDER`  This has worked flawlessly for the Windows computers.

For the Mac though, I have created a folder on the desktop, I have shared it (I made sure it was in the shared in the file sharing part of the system preferences and made sure the "shared" checkbox is checked in the folder info), but I cannot find what the network address is for the thing.  The scanner requires from a Mac an SMB share (which again, I have made sure that option is checked in the File Sharing menu).  I have tried `smb://MacBook-Pro.local/SHARED FOLDER` which the scanner said was an invalid address format, I have tried and all other formats I tried for the address and then tested have come back with "Unable to connect."  I have tried `\\MacBook-Pro.local\SHARED FOLDER`, `\\MacBook-Pro\SHARED FOLDER`, `\\MacBook-Pro.local/SHARED FOLDER`, and `\\MacBook-Pro/SHARED FOLDER` (I tried both \ and / in the address because I know that the Windows convention is for the back slash and it's an SMB share, but Mac, being a Unix system uses forward slashes for its file systems.)

Everything I have searched has shown me how to make a shared folder on Mac, but nothing has told me how to find out the exact network address of the darn thing.

Comment: Update: The macbook started showing up in the network area of the local windows computers.  I have the exact network address, and I have the credentials correct.  I even tested permissions by transferring a file into the folder.  I know everything is set up correctly on the mac, and I have set up the scanner the exact same way that I set it up for the Windows computers, and now the scanner just says "Unable to connect."

So while I know I have everything set up correctly, I'm stuck again.

Comment: Check the Mac's Console log for the time connection was attempted. I'm not certain, but it may be related to this - https://superuser.com/questions/888923/specific-windows-7-to-mac-smb-share-rejected-others-ok-troubleshooting/894691#894691

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'MacBook-Pro.local' trying using the computers IP Address. Also make sure that you have added the user to the folders permission.

Is this peer-to-peer or in a domain?

Comment: It's peer-to-peer, and unfortunately they have a DHCP setup, and the person comes and goes with the laptop so I cannot rely on it being the same IP in the future.  I also made sure that the folder has read&write permissions for "everyone" as well as the user (which the scanner should be trying to sign in with and I put the correct credentials into the system).

Comment: @ChrisRevocateur If you have access to the DHCP server (or whatever device doing the DHCP) you can set up DHCP reservation so that particular device will ALWAYS get the same IP (and the IP is outside the range that the DHCP can assign - so for example the DHCP is giving IP from 192.168.1.1 to 200, set the device to have DHCP reservation that gives it 192.168.1.210 for example).

Comment: So I found the network address, no need for a static IP.  But now it still won't connect.  See comment on OP.