# How to share folder from Mac to Windows 10 PC?

Tags: windows-10, mac, lan, file-sharing, osx-el-capitan

I have a Macbook Air "Early 2014" with OS 10.11.6.

I also have a Windows 10 desktop.

From my Windows 10 desktop, I want to browse a shared folder on the Macbook.

I have tried following [Apple's documentation here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25346?locale=en_US) (e.g. *Select “Share files and folders using SMB.”*).

I've been running into 3 different errors, depending on what I try.

For example, in Windows Explorer, I've tried browsing to `\\kvbair` (which is the name of my Macbook). I've also tried browsing directly to the Macbook's IP (`\\192.168.1.103` instead of `\\KVBAIR`).

Here are the different errors I've gotten:

### Error #1

> "[Server] is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this
>   network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out
>   if you have access permissions. The stub received bad data."

[image]

### Error #2

> Windows cannot access [server]. You do not have permission to access
>   [server]. Contact your network administrator to request access.

[image]

### Error #3

It always says "The user name or password is incorrect", regardless of which credentials I try.

[image]

**What else I've tried:**

- Removing any old credentials from Windows "Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager".
- 3 different sets of credentials: my main Macbook credentials, *new* credentials on the Macbook created specifically for this purpose, and my main Windows credentials.
- Disabling the Windows Firewall
- Changing various settings within Windows "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings"
- Uninstalling and reinstalling "Client for Microsoft Networks" in my Windows wifi adapter
- Changing the Local Security Policy > "Network security: LAN manager authentication level" from "Not defined" to "Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated"

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I also tried changing Local Security Policy > "Network security: LAN manager authentication level" from "Not defined" to "Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated" (https://superuser.com/a/894691/74576).

Comment: Please [edit] any updates into the question.

Comment: Are you using the proper username to get into the Mac? If memory serves, it'll use the username you're logged into in Windows.

Comment: possibly related? https://superuser.com/questions/888923/specific-windows-7-to-mac-smb-share-rejected-others-ok-troubleshooting

Comment: @MMB I've tried 3 different sets of credentials: my main Macbook credentials, *new* credentials on the Macbook created specifically for this purpose, and my main Windows credentials.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, but I'd already tried that link, as mentioned above.