# Can't access shared Windows drive from Mac

Tags: networking, windows-10, macos, file-sharing

I am trying to access a drive that is shared (G:/ drive) from a Mac. The windows computer is using Windows 10. Here are some infos about both computers.

**Windows**

- All sharing options are activated in the Network Center -> Advanced Parameters (private, public and all networks)
- Firewall is disabled
- Workgroup name is: `WORKGROUP`
- G:/ is shared with `Everyone` and having all autorisations
- This PC's name is `Central`

I've tried accessing this drive with another Windows computer in the same network and it worked. It doesn't work for the Mac.

**Mac**

- File Sharing is activated
- SMB is activated and my Mac User is the one that can use it
- Workgroup name is : `WORKGROUP`
- Windows' PC name `Central` is actually found by the Mac

When I tried to connect to `Central`, that being by either it's name or the IP adress (IPV4), it shows me connection failed. It's instantaneous, it doesn't even seem to attempt to find something.

For reference i've used this guide amongst others:
https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204445

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to enable SMBv1, which is by default not installed in Windows 10
for security reasons.

This is the procedure :

- Run *Control Panel -> Programs and Features*
- Click *Turn Windows features on or off*
- Click next to *SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support* so it marked as checked
- Click *OK* and allow boot

If this does not solve the problem, disable SMBv1 using this same method by unchecking
the option.

Comment: @ harry - I bow to your superior knowledge, but am reminded of a similar issue I had a & wondered if it was possibly relevant - https://superuser.com/questions/888923/specific-windows-7-to-mac-smb-share-rejected-others-ok-troubleshooting

Comment: @Tetsujin: I don't think so. If I remember right, SMBv1 was enabled by default in Windows 7.

Comment: OK, no worries - it just sparked a vague memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That was exactly what I needed to enable to make it work.